# Pack/unpack and BSON encode/decode dat

Tags: php, python

We have an iOS app that sends data in an encoded format. In PHP the following code will decode it properly.

```
bson_decode(pack("H*", $hex_string));
```

In Python, the following code will create a valid encoded object that the PHP code can then decode (`data` is a `dict` in this).

```
from bson import BSON
def encode(data):
    return str(BSON.encode(data)).encode('hex')
```

The following Python code will decode a string that was encoded by the above Python code:

```
from bson import BSON
def parse(str):
    hexed = str.decode('hex')
    return BSON.decode(BSON(hexed))
```

In theory that should decoded data sent from the app as well. But it throws the following exceptions:

```
bson.errors.InvalidBSON: bad eoo
```

It looks like the Objective C code that encodes the data in the app adds some extra padding. If I remove the last characters from the app encoded string it works. Is there anything I can do to account for this? Changing the app code is NOT possible. Even if it were there are millions of device running the old code which I need to support so I still need to have a fix for this.

Comment: *"If I remove the last characters from the app encoded string it works. Is there anything I can do to account for this?"* Remove the last characters?

Comment: That is actually my hack to accomodate this. I logged 5k of the app encoded strings. Looped through each one cutting off one character from the end until found a length that decodes properly. I compiled a list of the 5 most common lengths. If those fail then I then I go through the string char by char.

Answer (score 0):

According the [BSON specification](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification), BSON documents must be terminated with a NULL byte (`\x00`). Have you checked if the byte string you are trying to decode is NULL terminated? If not, you may need to append a NULL byte at the end.